# DisclosureIndicator not shown

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift

i've created a UITableView and used the standard UITableViewCell and added a accessoryType, but whatever i do it does not seem to appear. How come is that? here is my code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {

    switch indexPath.row
        {

    case 0:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = "Kontakt os"
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator

        return cell


    case 1:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = "Privatpolitik"
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator

        return cell

    case 2:

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = "Vilkår"
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator

        return cell

    default:
        println()
        }




    return nil
}
```

[image]

Comment: You can easily find out why just by stepping through the code

Comment: Are the text for `textlabel`s getting displayed properly?

Comment: yes they are i've added a image

Comment: @gamerChristian May I ask why you're using a switch case inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method and instantiating cells inside its cases? That's a lot of repeating code. Also I'm confused how you're able to use that method without removing all those optional unwrapping `!` symbols because normally Xcode 6 gives an error if you don't. I simply did [this](http://pastie.org/9609816) and it [works](http://i.imgur.com/mDtdrBk.png).

Comment: I'm doing that since this is just a prototype and there will come more code, but right now i'm trying to show the disclosureIndicator

Comment: Okay it worked if i changed it from viewController to a UITableViewController?